# Is there a way to programatically checkpoint a flow and retry it (in Corda OS 4.6 version) from that point in case of following failure?

Tags: corda

Imagine that at some point in the flow the next instruction might fail. I would like to create a checkpoint before trying it. Then if the instruction fails, a `HospitalizeFlowException` will be thrown. The flow will be sent to the flow hospital. Now the client which invoked this flow through the RPC client should be able to retry it from the last checkpoint. Is it possible to do that in Corda OS 4.6?

Answer (score 0):

I think we chatted on this question on slack (slack.corda.net for the curious) and essentially corda will handle your checkpoints for you. The flow messaging framework handles these kinds of things and trying to move around it can result in some subtle and hard-to-debug outcomes.

If your flow is hospitalized any operations / external IO can potentially happen again so ideally, the external io you do will be idempotent.

here’s  a good example of blocking I/O in a flow:

- https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/flow-database-access
- https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Basic/flow-http-access

good luck